# Price reductions on Xbox Live Arcade games

Tags: xbox-live-arcade

Do Xbox Live Arcade games ever reduce in price, if they are older or during special sale events? I know Gold members get a deal-of-the-week but am unaware of anything beyond that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deal of the week is not the only way prices are reduced on XBLA. There are more: there was also a Christmas promotion (a game a day) last year and [XBLA Inventory Blowout](http://majornelson.com/archive/2010/06/18/coming-soon-to-the-xbox-live-marketplace-june-18.aspx) this year.

[Major Nelson](http://majornelson.com/) is a good (and an advance) source of such information: [Major Nelson's deal tag](http://majornelson.com/archive/tags/Deal/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes they go on sale, or the creator can decide to change the price. During the summer, there are summer savings, and sometimes other ones too. It just varies.

Comment: Good news. Any tips for keeping track?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes after a year or so there will be a permanent price drop, but there's no guarantee. And there are special deals every now and then, but you can't really predict what they will be. I keep track of this by subscribing to Joystiq's "Now Playing" RSS feed: http://www.joystiq.com/tag/now-playing/rss.xml

Every Tuesday they list the new releases for all consoles, including XBLA games and XBLA price changes. It's nice because I only have to look at it once a week. I'm sure there are other sites with similar content; Joystiq's just the one I'm familiar with.

You might also want to check out http://www.cheapassgamer.com, though I found it took a much bigger commitment to keep up with it.